# resizing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm looking for JS or jQuery (core dependecy only) code that allows you to resize any html element, or just divs - could use div container for content.

The problem I'm having with jQuerys resizeable() function is it's dependencies with UI and the bloat that would bring to my rather slimmed codebase.  Also it only uses a corner handle for resizing where I'd like an interface more along the lines with how table and image resizing works in TinyMCE.

That is, a dashed border around the element to be resized, with 8 points to drag from. If you try the TinyMCE demo on their site you'll see what I mean. It allows for both aspect ratio to be kept and distorted based on dragging point.

Most hits I get on resizing is for a one time resize of images to fit the page width, but I'd love to be pointed in the right direction in case there is a snippet or jquery plugin out there that I've missed.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: what do you mean, i'm looking for a lib/plugin. haven't been desperate enough to code it myself yet, even if it may come to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same "problem" a couple months ago, did not want to use the jquery UI but wanted to resize... I came across this "custom event" plugin. Very light and does the job.

[threedubmedia jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag)

You can see a resizing demo at the bottom of the page.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Certainly the most promising one so far! Would have to do a fair amount of custom work on it, but at least I got a good starting point.  Do you happen to know if it redraw the DOM at resizing of for example DIV's?  Anyway, I guess I'll know soon enough.

Comment: Happy I could help! They say it doesn't alter the DOM, but I never looked into it myself. Anyway if it's the best answer you get, can you please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3's `resize`.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/uAzVY/

Not as much functionality as you want, though.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all with Opera, or I didn't figure out what to do. Either way, I'd need it in JS for other functionality, like a callback when the resize is done.